# Blender file keep crashing

Tags: blend-files

[image]

Somehow one of my blender files won’t open after crashing.
I keep getting this message that says blender quit unexpectedly every time l tried to open it.

I check the file size. It's only 107MB and l can open other files way bigger than this with no problem.

I tried the auto save recovery method and append, but none of these works.
I'm not sure why. Could anyone help me with this? I spent a day working on this scene and it would be very sad if l can’t open it.

Comment: Have you checked the crash logs? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html Alternatively/complementary, if you open Blender from command line (rather than by clicking on the GUI icon), you can look in the terminal after it crashes and usually will get a bit more information useful for figuring out what happened

Comment: THANKS! I guess l'm not technically savvy enough to use this method....

Answer (score 0):

### Check for saved versions

First, check if you have a `.blend1` file next to your `.blend` file. If so, give it a new name, remove the `1`, and try to open it in Blender. These `.blendX` files are copies of your precedent saves.

### Append in a new file

Open a new scene, delete everything, then got to the menu File > Append.

Navigate to your file. If you can double-click it and see a bunch of folders, good news, you might be able to recover some stuff.

Go in the Collections folder, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> and click the blue `Append` button.  If you are lucky enough, it will just append everything into your new scene, which you can then save safely.

If you are unable to append everything in the collections' folder, you can try to append only the first half of it, then the second one. Whichever half doesn't work, divide it by two and append them half by half again. Eventually you will find which collections cause issues. If collections are too wide, try objects instead.

If nothing can be done, well, sorry.

### How to prevent this issue in the future

Blender can keep a small history of your pretend saves via the "Save Versions" option in Edit > Preferences > Saves & Load:

[image: save versions]

That's what creates the `.blendX` when you same on the same file.

The second - and in my opinion the best, is to always save as a new file by simply incrementing your file name. You can do it manually by going to File > Save As > click the `+` button next to the save button > Save button.

Or, if you use the Pie Menus addon, the pie menu <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> have an incremental save option that does the same thing in one click:

[image: pie save]

Comment: Thank you! l tried both methods but still can't open my scene.... l guess my file is totally corrupted... what a bummer. but i will definitely use your advice for preventing this in the future

Comment: by any chance, could you try to upload you .blend and .blend1 files, for example on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the links here so we can try on our side?